# Authorization with apikey in headers using dio and generated client libraries by openapi-generator-dart

Tags: flutter, dart, api-key, openapi-generator, dio

I created client libraries in a flutter project using the DioNext generator from openapi-generator-dart.
The api I am trying to communicate with uses an apikey as the authentication method and it uses it in the url, i.e when I am accessing the api through my Google Chrome browser:
`https://api.hotelsexample.com/hotelfinder/v1/countries/en_US/hotels/A000293?apikey=9dhsu8d8-an9c-d40e1-a11c-5s84ddewda5`

Now the method generated to get, i.e. a hotel, by DioNext looks like the following, and there are many endpoints like this, so I do not want to change the generated code:

```
  Future<Response<Hotel>> hotelGET({ 
    required String countryId,
    required String hotelId,
    BuiltList<String>? fieldsFilter,
    CancelToken? cancelToken,
    Map<String, dynamic>? headers,
    Map<String, dynamic>? extra,
    ValidateStatus? validateStatus,
    ProgressCallback? onSendProgress,
    ProgressCallback? onReceiveProgress,
  }) async {
    final _path = r'/countries/{countryId}/hotels/{hotelId}'.replaceAll('{' r'countryId' '}', countryId.toString()).replaceAll('{' r'hotelId' '}', hotelId.toString());
    final _options = Options(
      method: r'GET',
      headers: <String, dynamic>{
        ...?headers,
      },
      extra: <String, dynamic>{
        'secure': <Map<String, String>>[
          {
            'type': 'apiKey',
            'name': 'apikey',
            'keyName': 'apikey',
            'where': 'query',
          },
        ],
        ...?extra,
      },
      validateStatus: validateStatus,
    );

    final _queryParameters = <String, dynamic>{
      if (fieldsFilter != null) r'fieldsFilter': encodeCollectionQueryParameter<String>(_serializers, fieldsFilter, const FullType(BuiltList, [FullType(String)]), format: ListFormat.multi,),
    };

    final _response = await _dio.request<Object>(
      _path,
      options: _options,
      queryParameters: _queryParameters,
      cancelToken: cancelToken,
      onSendProgress: onSendProgress,
      onReceiveProgress: onReceiveProgress,
    );

    Hotel _responseData;

    try {
      const _responseType = FullType(Hotel);
      _responseData = _serializers.deserialize(
        _response.data!,
        specifiedType: _responseType,
      ) as Hotel;

    } catch (error, stackTrace) {
      throw DioError(
        requestOptions: _response.requestOptions,
        response: _response,
        type: DioErrorType.other,
        error: error,
      )..stackTrace = stackTrace;
    }

    return Response<Hotel>(
      data: _responseData,
      headers: _response.headers,
      isRedirect: _response.isRedirect,
      requestOptions: _response.requestOptions,
      redirects: _response.redirects,
      statusCode: _response.statusCode,
      statusMessage: _response.statusMessage,
      extra: _response.extra,
    );
  }
```

Now, when I try to call the api using the following method:

```
void getmyhotel() async {
    final api = Hotelsexample().getReferencesApi();
    final countryId = "en_US";
    final hotelId = "A000293";

    try {
      final response = await api.hotelGET(
          countryId: countryId,
          hotelId: hotelId,
          headers: {"apikey": "9dhsu8d8-an9c-d40e1-a11c-5s84ddewda5"});
      print(answer);
    } catch (e) {
      print(
          "Exception: $e\n");
    }
  }
```

I get the error of an invalid apikey, so the apikey is not recognized by the api server.
Where do I have to place the apikey in my code?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All right, I solved the problem.
This time I downloaded the latest version of https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator.
It is a .jar file. I used the instructions on the github page to generate the files out of the .jar file and now I have client libraries, which are upgraded to null safety and do not need the use of dio.
With the code

```
defaultApiClient.getAuthentication<ApiKeyAuth>("apikey")!.apiKey =
        "9dhsu8d8-an9c-d40e1-a11c-5s84ddewda5";
```

I can now pass the apikey!

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass it as query instead of header.

Comment: Thank you for your solution.

Comment: Thank you for your solution.
When I change the generated code from `r'fieldsFilter'` to `r'apikey'` and add the following parameter to my class `getmyhotel()` : `fieldsFilter: BuiltList<String>(["9dhsu8d8-an9c-d40e1-a11c-5s84ddewda5"])`, then it works, but now I have to change every api class from the generated code and I can not use the fieldsfilter function any more. It would be better if I could pass the apikey in the header instead or if the openapi-generator-dart provides the possibility to pass the apikey as a query.